# How to create an <img> tag in tooltip using names from the csv data file

Tags: javascript, html, image, tooltip

I have a scatter plot graph of document filings over time.
I have a tooltip box that *pops up on mouseover of the data points, that provides text data*.  I would like to **include an image in each tooltip box**.
The data is drawn from a `.csv` file that includes a number of fields such as `DocName`, `FilingDate`, `DocNumber`, etc.
The images are each saved in an **"Images"** folder as `DocNumber.jpg`.
I was trying to cobble together a piece of code that would ***pick up the DocNumber from the csv file and create the correct html tag to make the image show up***....
So far all I've managed to get is a `"placeholder"` .
Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?
The code for the **mouseover** is below:

```
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(d.CCode + " " +d.DocNumber + "<br>" 
         +d.DocName + "<br>"
         + "Filing Date =" + formatTime(d.FilingDate) + "<br>"
         + "Status=" + d.Status + "<br>" 
         + '"<img src=/Images/"'+d.DocNumber+'".jpeg>"')  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX +10) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY -28) + "px");    
        })
```

Comment: put snapshot of your tooltip

Comment: Check the quotes in `'"<img src=/Images/"'+d.DocNumber+'".jpeg>"')`

Comment: @MareeA have you try my following code snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description**

Remove the single quotes around image tag and also before and after d.DocNumber. Following is the modified code snippet you my apply this.

**Code**

```
  .on("mouseover", function (d) {
     div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);
     div.html(d.CCode + " " + d.DocNumber + "<br>"
      + d.DocName + "<br>"
      + "Filing Date =" + formatTime(d.FilingDate) + "<br>"
      + "Status=" + d.Status + "<br>"
      + "<img src=/Images/" + d.DocNumber + ".jpeg>")
     .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
     .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  });
```

Comment: thanks. I did modify the code to what you've suggested, but I'm still seeing a placeholder icon instead of the images.  I'm about to go back and make sure I haven't made any typos.

Comment: Do I need to add anything in the tooltip definition to enable images? Currently I have:     var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

Comment: OK... found the problem... it was me.. very simple error..... should have been src=Images not src=/Images.   Now the code works beautifully.